# How to display xml text in html in angular js

Tags: html, xml, angularjs, user-interface

I have some data in string -

```
 var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel>    </rss>" ;
```

Now I want this string to be display on web page in proper xml format .

```
<channel>
   <title>
        RSS Title
   </title>
</channel>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Was expecting google-code-prettify would do the job but looks like it does not do indentation. With an additional plugin for indentation (vkbeautify) able to get the proper xml format with indentation.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Pep9HurLI8NPtAXRsoFD?p=preview

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <pre class="prettyprint lang-xml"></pre>
</div>

App.directive('prettyprint', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.text(vkbeautify.xml(scope.dom, 4));
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: hi, when i click button and update dom value is not reflecting, how to fix that?