# How do i prettify XML which is returned as a String in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, html

I have my HTML as below return something from Angular (my angular code is below)

```
<section>
    <p>{{xml}}</p>
</section>
```

And in Angular, from Java back-end, i am getting this "XML" as a string.

But I want to prettify it using the following plugin

https://github.com/krtnio/angular-pretty-xml

I don't know how to use this plugin after including it in my HTML file and this is where I ask for your help.

```
app.controller('xmlController', function($scope, $http){

    $http.get("/api/xml").then(function (response) {
        $scope.xml = response.data; //I need to PRETTIFY IT HERE ON $scope.xml
     });

});
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: maybe https://dzone.com/articles/visualizing-xml-graph-using

Comment: It is filter, it should be used as `<p>{{xml|prettyXml}}</p>`, but this is shoot in the dark as currently I cannot try it.

Comment: @WuDo I get an error when i try that. 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/unpr?p0=prettyXmlFilterProvider%20%3C-%20prettyXmlFilter

Comment: I have found pretty much interesting soluton mentioned here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31857502/how-to-display-xml-text-in-html-in-angular-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think you are missing something in the installation process.

First you have to install the package on your app:

Via Bower:

```
bower install angular-pretty-xml --save
```

Via npm:

```
npm install angular-pretty-xml --save
```

Make sure to **include it on your html file** within the `script` tag (unless you are using some automated packaging system like webpack or something else that bundles it for you), so that you can **add it as a dependency on your angular module declaration** like so:

```
angular
    .module('myApp', ['prettyXml'])
    .controller('xmlController', function($scope, $http){

        $http.get("/api/xml").then(function (response) {
            $scope.xml = response.data; //I need to PRETTIFY IT HERE ON $scope.xml
        });
    });
```

This way you'll be able to use the filter on your templates like so:

```
<p>{{ xml | prettyXml}}</p>
```

**References:**

[angular-pretty-xml](https://github.com/krtnio/angular-pretty-xml)